# Replace("this string that is a rule", "with this") in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have this variable with an address:

```
var address = "Portugal, RUA ENG.CAMILO MENDONCA-LOTE 139 - APARTADO 80-ZONA INDUSTRIAL, 5300-426 Bragança";
```

And I want to know if is there a way to instead using a fixed string in the first parameter of .Replace(,), to use a rule, like : from "- APARTADO" to ",", and then a fixed string as second paramenter.

Comment: I'd look into Regular Expressions (google it).

Comment: https://regex101.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you indicated your rule to be (anything from "- APARTADO" to a ,), you could use regex to achieve this.

```
var address = "Portugal, RUA ENG.CAMILO MENDONCA-LOTE 139 - APARTADO 80-ZONA INDUSTRIAL, 5300-426 Bragança";

var regex = new Regex("- APARTADO[^']*,");

var replacedAddress = regex.Replace(address, /* Your replacement value */);
```

In the example above the regex pattern breaks down as follows:

`"- APARTADO"`: matches the exact string you wanted to start with

`[^']*`: Matches any number of characters that is not a '

Comment: It is always helpful to include a detailed explanation of each RegEx token being used to facilitate the understanding of how the RegEx was created and why the token was used.

Comment: Thanks, I'am new to programming and never heard about Regex. This is an awesome feature.

Comment: Good point, @MetroSmurf. I have edited the answer with a token explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an approach using `string.split`. It takes a string, and stores it into a string array made up of fragments of your original string which is separated by a specified string. Then find the fragment of the string you want to replace, edit it, and then concatenate the string using `string.join`!

MSDN has some good documentation on this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx